# Couldn't deploy Rails + Tailwind on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, tailwind-css

I deploy the rails + tailwind app on Heroku but I failed with the below error.

```
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Function rgb is missing argument $green.
        on line 607 of stdin
>>   color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
```

Here's how I installed Tailwind to the app.

```
bin/bundle add tailwindcss-rails
bin/rails tailwindcss:install
```

Comment: Hey, mate, did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There：https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6738

add `config.assets.css_compressor = nil` to `config/environments/production.rb` file

Answer (score 3):

You can check the comment here https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails with regards to `sassc-rails`. It seems like there's an incompatibility with that gem. For example, you may have to remove sass-rails ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Probably Tailwind produces too modern CSS for SASSC though I need SASSC. Is there a solution for Sprockets to pick the Tailwind.css file without having SASSC to read it ? I have been thinking of exporting Tailwind.css strait to public but I am not a great fan of this.